# Negative and positive valued series, convergence set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{1+x^{2n}} .
$$
It is straightforward to show that the series converges pointwise in 
$$
\left]-\infty, -\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right[ \quad \bigcup \quad  \left] \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, +\infty \right[
$$
but I can't find a simple/quick way to prove the following:
(a) the series converges even in $\left] 0,  \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$;
(b) the series does not converge in $\left]-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},0 \right[$.
Any idea?

Comment: Please, how is that straightforward? For example, for $\;x=\frac12<\frac{-1+\sqrt5}2\;$ it converges

Answer (score 1):

We're given the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(x-1)^n\over 1+x^{2n}}
$$

- In $]0,1[$ the terms are asymptotically equivalent to ${(x-1)^n}$ that form a convergent geometric series.
- In $]1,\infty[$ the terms are asymptotically equivalent to $\left({x-1\over x^{2}}\right)^n$ that also form a convergent geometric series iff
  $$
  {x-1\over x^2}<1\implies  x^2-x+1>0\implies\left(x-0.5\right)^2+0.75>0
  $$
  which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Using d'Alembert's criterion we have

- for $x\in (-\infty,-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) \cup (1,\infty)$ series is convergent

$$
\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{1+x^{2(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{1+x^{2n}}{|x-1|^n}=|x-1| \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{x^{2(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^{2(n+1)}}+1} \to \frac{|x-1|}{x^2}<1,
$$

- for $x\in (-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},-1)$ series is divergent

$$
\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{1+x^{2(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{1+x^{2n}}{|x-1|^n}=|x-1| \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{x^{2(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^{2(n+1)}}+1} \to \frac{|x-1|}{x^2}>1,
$$

- for $x\in (-1,0)$ series is divergent

$$
\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{1+x^{2(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{1+x^{2n}}{|x-1|^n}\to |x-1|>1,
$$

- for $x\in (0,1)$ series is convergent

$$
\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{1+x^{2(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{1+x^{2n}}{|x-1|^n}\to |x-1|<1.
$$

At the points $x\in\{-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, -1, 0\}$ series is divergent because limit of the summand doesn't exist. Of course, at the point $x=1$ series converges.